# display object from separate class using actionListener

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that creates a smiley. When I run the code below everything works out and 9 smiley objects are created and displayed to the grid layout. However I would like to take the block of code that loops 9 times and creates/displays 9 smileys and call it when I click the creatSmiley button.

However when I move that piece of code to the actionEvent, nothing happens when I run the code and press the button.

The smiley class that the object is created from extends jpanel and uses the paint method to create a smiley face.

Any tips?

```
      public class SmileyGrid extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JPanel buttonPanel, panel, facePanel;
private JButton pumpkinButton, smileyButton;



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SmileyGrid myGrid = new SmileyGrid(); 
    myGrid.setSize(700, 700);
    myGrid.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    myGrid.createGUI();
    myGrid.setVisible(true);

}

public SmileyGrid()
{

}

private void createGUI()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout (new BorderLayout());

    facePanel = new JPanel();
    facePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    facePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
    add(facePanel);

    smileyButton = new JButton("Create Smiley");
    pumpkinButton = new JButton("Create Pumpkin");

    smileyButton.addActionListener(this);


    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    add (buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    buttonPanel.add(smileyButton);
    buttonPanel.add(pumpkinButton);


    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Color color1=new Color(r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256));
        Color color2=new Color(r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256));
        Color color3=new Color(r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256));
        Color color4=new Color(r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256));

        Smiley mySmiley = new Smiley(color1, color2, color3, color4);

        facePanel.add(mySmiley);
    }

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{  

}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that receives the new Smileys after add all of them.

Comment: I thought of that, where would I place it exactly? Id assume in the actionperformed but I don't really know how to use it and reference the container.

Comment: EDIT - I added both of those statements to the bottom of the actionPerformed and it worked. However when I click the button it just adds additional smileys. Any way to simply create new ones when the button is clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

So, I took your basic code, modified, because you didn't include the `Smiley` class, moved the `for-loop` to the `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed` method and called `revalidate` and `repaint` on the `facePanel` after I'd create a bunch of new "fake smilies" and it worked just fine for me

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SmileyGrid extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel buttonPanel, panel, facePanel;
    private JButton pumpkinButton, smileyButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SmileyGrid myGrid = new SmileyGrid();
        myGrid.setSize(700, 700);
        myGrid.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        myGrid.createGUI();
        myGrid.setVisible(true);

    }

    public SmileyGrid() {

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        facePanel = new JPanel();
        facePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        facePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        add(facePanel);

        smileyButton = new JButton("Create Smiley");
        pumpkinButton = new JButton("Create Pumpkin");

        smileyButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        buttonPanel.add(smileyButton);
        buttonPanel.add(pumpkinButton);

//        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
//            Random r = new Random();
//            Color color1 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
//            Color color2 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
//            Color color3 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
//            Color color4 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
//
//            Smiley mySmiley = new Smiley(color1, color2, color3, color4);
//
//            facePanel.add(mySmiley);
//        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            Color color1 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
            Color color2 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
            Color color3 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
            Color color4 = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));

//            Smiley mySmiley = new Smiley(color1, color2, color3, color4);
            JPanel mySmiley = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(20, 20);
                }                
            };
            mySmiley.setBackground(color1);

            facePanel.add(mySmiley);
        }
        facePanel.revalidate();
        facePanel.repaint();

    }
}
```

If you have any other issues, then it's probably with your `Smiley` class

Comment: Works great when I use your code, with my Smiley class. However, upon an additional click of the button, instead of redrawing the smileys with new random colors, it just smushes an additional smiley into each grid location.

Comment: So you want to remove the old smilies first or do you want to keep adding them?

Comment: I would like them removed and re painted upon an additional button click. This way new smileys would replace the old ones with new random colors

Comment: You need to read the JavaDocs in more depth - `facePanel.removeAll()` is what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you, I added that right before the loop starts and it works as I want it to. I appreciate your help and I will take the time to read the JavaDocs on that function. It is great learning new things like this.